# Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, prisma

I am having a problem with my nodeJS back-end. I want to create a docker compose environment but I keep getting this error when I try to start my Prisma NodeJS app. I already tried lots of things and I can't find any usable solutions on Google. The application works without docker.

Docker compose file:

```
  endbit-express:
    container_name: endbit-express
    build: ./endbit-express
    volumes:
      - ./endbit-express:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/endbit
    networks:
      - endbit

  mysql:
    container_name: endbit-mysql
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6033:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=endbit
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - endbit
```

Docker file:

```
FROM node:17.4.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN prisma generate

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Error:

```
endbit-express  | > express@0.0.0 start
endbit-express  | > node ./bin/www
endbit-express  |
endbit-express  | /app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3
endbit-express  |     throw new Error(
endbit-express  |     ^
endbit-express  |
endbit-express  | Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
endbit-express  | In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues
endbit-express  |     at new PrismaClient (/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:3:11)
endbit-express  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/passport.js:7:16)
endbit-express  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
endbit-express  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
endbit-express  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
endbit-express  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
endbit-express  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
endbit-express  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
endbit-express  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:7:1)
endbit-express  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
endbit-express  |
endbit-express  | Node.js v17.4.0
```

Comment: The `volumes:` mounts hide basically everything that the Dockerfile sets up; does deleting that block help?  You will also run into connectivity problems since the Dockerfile won't be able to connect to the database (_e.g._, [NestJS in Docker can't do a Prisma Migrate on Postgres in another Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615707/nestjs-in-docker-cant-do-a-prisma-migrate-on-postgres-in-another-docker-contain)).  If you can check the generated files into source control that might be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer myself: I am using a docker compose file, and Docker doesn't recognize the localhost:3306 URL. In docker compose you need to link the containers by their name, so I changed the backend component environment with this (host = docker service name):

```
environment:
  - DB_HOST=mysql
  - DB_USER=root
  - DB_PASSWORD=root
  - DB_NAME=endbit-express
  - DB_PORT=3306
```

Answer (score 1):

add `RUN npm i -g prisma` before `RUN prisma generate` it should work