# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `crdb`:`26257`

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma, cockroachdb

Framework:Nest js
ORM: Prisma
Database: Cockroach DB (like postgres)
OS: Debian 12

I want to run a container using Docker Compose and am getting this error.

```
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": CockroachDB database "defaultdb", schema "public" at "crdb:26257"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `crdb`:`26257`

Please make sure your database server is running at `crdb`:`26257`.

The command '/bin/sh -c npx prisma db push' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

The problem is in the Database_URL, I'm sure because I ran this project before without Docker

ENV file:
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@crdb:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable"`

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  crdb:
   container_name: crdb
   image: cockroachdb/cockroach:latest
   ports:
     - "26257:26257"
     - "8080:8080"
   command: start-single-node --insecure 
   volumes:
     - ./data/node_1:/cockroach/cockroach-data

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nest
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - crdb
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["fullTextSearch", "fullTextIndex"] 
}

datasource db {
  provider = "cockroachdb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npx prisma db push

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm run build

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As production

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

Without a description of the app service, DB starts

I tried to make the following URLs like this
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@localhost:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable"`
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@127.0.0.1:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable"`
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@crdb1:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable"`(crdb - service; crdb1 - container)
Once I was able to find out the ip of a container using docker inspect and docker ps, but I’m not sure that it was the ip of that container (how would I know if it doesn’t start?).

So I'm thinking...maybe I need to define a network? Because when the database is initialized, the network name is displayed in the console(after `docker-compose system prune`).
Or i cant connect to single-node?
In a similar question, the person deletes the database from the OS and it helps... should I try?

Comment: Please remove the 'depends_on' since it's not needed. Can you try with: DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@crdb:26257/defaultdb?schema=public"

Comment: @sylar12
I remove the 'depends_on'. Also change 
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@crdb:26257/defaultdb?schema=public"
AND
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root@crdb:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=disable&schema=public"
But the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66683060/23267968

I think it's about my problem.But I misunderstand a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that!(probably)

So i create a entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

npx prisma db push

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

And add in Dockerfile
`ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]` instead off `npx prisma db push`.
And it's works for me.

Why it's works? - link in my 2nd comment

Comment: After I have a problem
`PrismaClientInitializationError: error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.`

Solution:
Add to app service in Docker compose
```env_file:
      - .env```